# trying to hide multiple classes on larger screens using CSS media queries?

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, responsiveness

I am using CSS media queries to display multiple classes ONLY on screens smaller than 760px. I wrote this code:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 760px) {
    .picleft, .picright, .piclefttext, .picrighttext {
        display:none;
    }
    .picbottom, .picbottomtext {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

However, this hides the classes on all screen sizes. When I changed "min-width" to "max-width", it displays them on all screen sizes. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You probably tested this incorrectly on wrong sizes. Try using your mobile phone and change `min-width` to `max-width`

Comment: Works fine here. https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/LLg9zvo7/ So, can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue?